# How to separate using read_csv with 2 instances

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a txt file that look like this

```
P SPB:0 curT:36C curNandT:25C
P SPB:1 curT:36C curNandT:25C
P SPB:2 curT:37C curNandT:28C
P SPB:3 curT:37C curNandT:29C
P SPB:4 curT:38C curNandT:29C
```

I want to separate them with ' ' and ':'
how should I do it based on:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename.txt, sep=???, header=None)
print(df)
```

Comment: what did you try and what was the problem?

Comment: I tried df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None)  but it only help separate with ' '

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sep='[ :]'`

```
pd.read_csv('filename', sep='[ :]', header=None)
```

output:

```
   0    1  2     3    4         5    6
0  P  SPB  0  curT  36C  curNandT  25C
1  P  SPB  1  curT  36C  curNandT  25C
2  P  SPB  2  curT  37C  curNandT  28C
3  P  SPB  3  curT  37C  curNandT  29C
4  P  SPB  4  curT  38C  curNandT  29C
```

Answer (score 0):

From Panda's docs on [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv), parameter `sep`:

> In addition, separators **longer than 1 character** and different from '\s+' will be **interpreted as regular expressions** and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'.

So you could pass separator argument as regex `sep = "\s|:"` to split by whitespace or colon.